Do all possible theories of quantum gravity have amplitudes?
There are many possible models of quantum gravity, some more developed than others (including: String theory, M-theory, supergravity, loop quantum gravity, causal sets, causal dynamical triangulation, twistor theory...etc)
Since all these models would consider particles and interactions between them, shouldn't all they trivially have scattering amplitudes (even if they have not been modelled yet)?

It depends on what you mean by Quantum gravity models. The idea of Quantum mechanics is built on the idea of Hilbert spaces. The "state" of a system is a vector in this space and that vector changes or evolves with time which gives the dynamics of the system. Any experiments performed in the system, or observables, are (Hermitian) operators that may have particular values at different states. Scattering matrix is one such operator which helps to calculate the Cross section of particles after a scattering event. The actual observable is the Cross Section, which is real and not the Scattering matrix, which is usually complex and needs to be squared.
So, if the quantum gravity model is written in the language of Hilbert spaces and state vectors, then the answer would be yes. There must be Scattering matrices which we will square and get the cross section and then give to experimentalists to verify our predictions. But a model need not be written in this language at all. There may be newer, better ways of writing down cross sections directly, even including all quantum interactions and taking care of things like superposition, entanglement.
The absolute crucial thing for any given theory is to predict the values of observable quantitites. The way to reach the value is just formalism. Since Scattering matrix is not an observable (only its square is), there is no hard requirement of it to be a part of your predictions.

even if there are alternative ways of formulating a theory that do not include a scattering matrix could there be an equivalent way of formulating them that includes scattering amplitudes? @Ari

Not necessarily. But it is highly likely that such a formulation will probably exist. All theories of Quantum gravity only need to produce results for observables. But since at low energies these observables have a Hilbert space description, even for this new theory something like "scattering amplitude" should effectively exist.

And is there any formulation which does not have any equivalence to scattering amplitudes? Or you were talking about a hypothetical future approach? @Ari

No I was speaking of hypothetical approaches.
